# How to extract a particular string from a String variable in php?

Tags: php, string, extract

I have string values related to images in a variable **$photo** covered by curly braces. I get this value from MySQL table. It has **Image name, alt text, and image caption** together in the string variable **$photo**.
I want to extract image name, alt, and image caption covered by curly brackets.

I've added code that has the string value below,

```
<?php
$photo =' {"imagename":
    {"filename":"imagename.jpg","alt":"Hunting Rifle","caption":"This is Hunter Image"}
}';
?>
```

I want to get filename and alt stings separately and  store it in new variables separately[$filename,$alt] .

Anyone knows how to extract these particular strings from a string variable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$jdphoto = json_decode($photo);

$imagename = $jdphoto->imagename;

$filename = $imagename->filename;
$alt = $imagename->alt;
$caption = $imagename->caption;
```

Answer (score 3):

That's [JSON](http://json.org/), so use [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

Comment: Hi @Matt Ball, Its Extracting well. I've never used json in my previous projects. Thank you.